# Can't receive APDU data with Arduino NFC module

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, apdu, hce

I'm trying to use HCE on my LG G2 and send some data to Arduino Uno with Elechouse NFC module 2.0.

The problem is that `nfc.inDataExchange(selectApdu, sizeof(selectApdu), response, &responseLength)` always returns `false`. What's going wrong?

On the [Arduino forums](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,201133.0.html),
MisterFrench got it working and I'm doing things using exactly the same principle. I took the following from Android HCE examples and just send some rubbish data:

```
@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received APDU: " + ByteArrayToHexString(commandApdu));
    // If the APDU matches the SELECT AID command for this service,
    // send the loyalty card account number, followed by a SELECT_OK status trailer (0x9000).
    if (Arrays.equals(SELECT_APDU, commandApdu)) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(Build.MANUFACTURER);
        stringBuilder.append("#");
        stringBuilder.append(Build.MODEL);
        stringBuilder.append(((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId());
        String data = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "Data send");

        return ConcatArrays(data.getBytes(), SELECT_OK_SW);
    } else {
        return UNKNOWN_CMD_SW;
    }
}
```

And on the Arduino side, I took code from the Arduino forum and changed it a little. Now it looks like

```
void loop(void) {
    bool success;
    Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");

    success = nfc.inListPassiveTarget();
    if(success) {
        Serial.println("Found something!");
        uint8_t selectApdu[] = { 
          0x00, /* CLA */
          0xA4, /* INS */
          0x04, /* P1  */
          0x00, /* P2  */
          0x05, /* Length of AID  */
          0xF2, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22,
          0x00  /* Le  */};

        uint8_t response[256];
        uint8_t responseLength = sizeof(response);

        success = nfc.inDataExchange(selectApdu, sizeof(selectApdu), response, &responseLength);

        if(success) {
            Serial.print("RAW: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < responseLength; ) {
                Serial.print(response[i++]);
                Serial.print(" ");
            }
            Serial.println(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < responseLength; i++) {
                Serial.print((char)response[i]);
                Serial.print(" ");
            }
            Serial.println(" ");
        }
        else{
            Serial.println("Failed sending SELECT AID"); 
        }
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Didn't find anything!");
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

---

I'm using Arduino UNO, NFC library "PN532" from https://github.com/elechouse/PN532

Comment: Your SELECT command APDU does not contain an Le field, however you return a response APDU with a data length of more than zero bytes. Setting the Le field in the command APDU to 0x00 would make sense in your case. Not sure if that causes the problem though.

Comment: @MichaelRoland I've added Le field, but nothing changes, keep receiving "Waiting for an ISO14443A card
Found something!
Failed sending SELECT AID
" message

Answer (score 0):

Obviously these lines will cause a problem:

```
uint8_t response[256];
uint8_t responseLength = sizeof(response);

success = nfc.inDataExchange(selectApdu, sizeof(selectApdu), response, &responseLength);
```

In the first line, you create an array of 256 bytes. In the next line you assign the size of that array to an 8-bit unsigned integer (`uint8_t`) variable. A `uint8_t` can only hold a value between 0 and 255 (= 2^8-1). Thus, the size of `response` (= 256) will cause an overflow. This results in `responseLength` being set to 0 (= 256 modulo 2^8). Consequently, the response length you feed into `nfc.inDataExchange()` is too short to hold any response.

So using

```
uint8_t response[255];
uint8_t responseLength = sizeof(response);
```

should work.

Comment: Just one more thing incorrect. First time I brought phone to reader, I got this answer: "76, 71, 69, 35, 76, 71, 45, 68, 56, 48, 50, 35, 144, 0", which in ACSII means "LGE#LG-D802#", that's exactly what I want. But after that, every time I bring phone, I'm reading "1, 71, 69, 35, 76, 71, 45, 68, 56, 48, 50, 35, 144, 0" or "11, 71, 69, 35, 76, 71, 45, 68, 56, 48, 50, 35, 144, 0". You see, first digit changed to 1 or 11. And it keeps till I physically restart arduino by reconnecting USB cable. Reset button doesn't fix this.

Comment: Did you change anything else in the code you posted in your question? Seems that at least the Android code must have changed...

Comment: Yes. I just removed code block that retrieves IMEI, and added leading space to keep needed data unchaged (only space character is changed now). I think problem may be with buffer, because when I bring NFC tag to reader, it keeps me showing "1, 71, 69, 35, 76 ...",

Comment: You might want to start a new question (including the *current* code parts, debug output, etc) then.

Answer (score 0):

This might be off topic but I was following the same exact code that you've posted here but I'm using Seeed Studio's NFC Shield V2. I think it might be helpful for others as well. I found out that once I removed the last byte in the selectApdu array from this:

```
uint8_t selectApdu[] = { 
      0x00, /* CLA */
      0xA4, /* INS */
      0x04, /* P1  */
      0x00, /* P2  */
      0x05, /* Length of AID  */
      0xF2, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22,
      0x00  /* Le  */};
```

To this:

```
uint8_t selectApdu[] = { 
          0x00, /* CLA */
          0xA4, /* INS */
          0x04, /* P1  */
          0x00, /* P2  */
          0x05, /* Length of AID  */
          0xF2, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22};
```

And that ended up allowing my Samsung Note 4 to communicate with the example android_hce provided with the Arduino and Seeed Studio libraries.